# 2 results with 2 where in one select statement in sql-server

Tags: sql-server

Let's say.. I have two statements

```
select min(Log_In_Time) from tbl where (event_ID=4)
select max(Log_Off_Time) from tbl where (event_ID=5)
```

How can I combine that 2 statement into one select statement which is resulted in 2 column like..

```
select min(Log_In_Time), max(Log_Off_Time) from tbl where ???????????????????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a CASE statement:

```
Select 
MIN (case when event_ID = 4 then Log_In_Time else null end) as MinTime,
MAX (case when event_ID = 5 then Log_Off_Time else null end) as MaxTime
from tbl
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I didn't make it clear I don't want them in same column. I know I can the way you did..

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(Log_In_Time) from tbl where (event_ID=4)
union all
select max(Log_Off_Time) from tbl where (event_ID=5)
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I didn't make it clear I don't want them in same column. I know I can the way you did..